# Make the contents of a .md file the body of an email for outlook using powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, markdown

I want to take the contents of an .md file and have it appear in the body of a generated email for outlook.  I can generate the email just find but the body gives the following error and I have yet to find a work around.

Error:

```
The object does not support this method.
At line:6 char:1
+ $new.HTMLBody = $a
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Code:

```
$out= New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
# $sign= Get-Content "C:\Users\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\sign.htm"
$recipient= "user@.com"
$new= $out.CreateItem(0)
$new.Subject = "Meeting details"
$a = Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\file.md"
$new.HTMLBody = $a
$new.Recipients.Add($recipient) 
$new.save() 
# $new.HTMLBody += $sign

$display= $new.GetInspector
$display.Display()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around the error message you posted, you need to read your file as a string rather than an array of strings. The reason is because `$new.Body` expects a string. By default, `Get-Content` returns an array with each line of a file being an element of that array. You can change this behavior with the `-Raw` switch, which will read the contents as one string.

```
$a = Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\file.md" -Raw
```

If the `-Raw` switch changes the newline formatting, you can always just join the default `Get-Content` array with newline characters of your choosing.

```
$a = Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\file.md"
$new.HTMLBody = $a -join "`r`n"
```

You can see the type differences in your original code using the `GetType()` method available to PowerShell objects.

```
$a.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


$new.Body.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: I attempted to use the `-Raw` command but then the MD file lost all it's formatting.  It came in as one long string.

Comment: Ok. That is probably just the newline formatting. You can replace lone \n characters with \r\n. The other option is to drop the -raw switch and then join everything back together with \r\n.

Comment: @Keith, I made an update that may help out with your formatting.